# Macro to make class noncopyable

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, noncopyable, deleted-functions

Is there any problem with following macro that makes a class non-copyable?

```
#define PREVENT_COPY(class_name) \
class_name(const class_name&) = delete;\
class_name& operator=(const class_name&) = delete;

class Foo
{
public:
    PREVENT_COPY(Foo)

    // .......
};
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a continuation-slash on the first line of your macro.

Comment: _"Is their any problem with following macro that makes class noncopyable?"_ Yes, it makes your code unreadable (less reliable) for anyone else.

Comment: @abelenky, moving an object isn't the same as copying it.  Part of the point of *having* move constructors is to allow moving of things that can't be copied (such as `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I disagree, it's a lot more readable than a bunch of deleted functions/tors in the body of every class you don't want to copy.

Comment: I don't understand, placing the copy constructor and assignment *declarations* in the `private` section (without any implementation) should prevent copying. What's the need for the `= delete`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews:  `private` is the "old way", and worked pretty good.  But it still meant that objects could copy themselves.  `= delete` is the new, C++11 way, and essentially forbids using that operation (which would otherwise be automatically generated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, macros are generally constructed so they require a semi-colon at the end of the line, just like normal statements.

Therefore, I suggest:

```
#define PREVENT_COPY(class_name) class_name(const class_name&) = delete;\
                                 class_name& operator=(const class_name&) = delete
```

Usage:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    PREVENT_COPY(Foo); // Semi-colon required.

    // .......
};
```